# Reload the whole dataTable when click on a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a Up vote functionality in my jQuery Data Table. When I click on the up vote button an ajax function is called and increment the counter in my SQL table via PHP. All I want was to update the counter on displayed on my data Table as well just like how stack overflow up vote works. I researched a bit and found web sockets are able to perform this feature, but I don't want to spend more time on this project and learn web sockets.

The second solution was to update the data Table when I make the Ajax call But for some reason it's not working either.

**I am not using Ajax to render whole data into my data Table Just my up vote is doing an ajax call**

My ajax call:

```
<script>

function upvotebutton(element){  
$.post("voting.php/",
{
topicid: $(element).val() 
 },
function(data){
 $('#example').DataTable().ajax.reload(); 
},
);

};
</script>
```

The above code is giving me an error says: 404 object.txt not found in my Ajax request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 404 would be returned from the server-side - so it really is saying that the file `object.txt` isn't on the server. Have you specified that file when defining the DataTables's Ajax properties? This reference page may [help](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()).